# Is it possible to get browserstack/lambdatest session url from t object?

Tags: testcafe

As an example with LT. The default reporter logs the following info once the test is started. I would like to get the session URL from t object(do not want to implement custom reporter only for that). Is it possible?

- Safari 17.1 / iOS 17.1 ( https://automation.lambdatest.com/logs/?sessionID=some-id )

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a T object? Is there any specific API you are looking to use?

Comment: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402665/reference/test-api/testcontroller

Comment: The link you added contains no information. Please share more details on what exactly you want to obtain and from where (location, request, etc.).

Comment: I need to get the link to BS/LT session, which appears in default testcafe report once execution is started.
Here is an example, not sure what is not clear here.. let me know please.
Safari 17.1 / iOS 17.1 ( https://automation.lambdatest.com/logs/?sessionID=some-id )

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the `BrowserStack/LambdaTest` session URL from the `t` object with `t.testRun.browserConnection.userAgent` and use a RegExp to extract necessary information from the string.

However, It's not part of public API and can be changed at any time. Please use it with caution.

Comment: Tried that one, by some reason there were no url :(